# Fetch a value of a property of an object in ArrayList

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist

I have initialized an `ArrayList` in C# for windows form application. I am adding new objects with few properties of each object in the `ArrayList`, such as:

```
ArrayList FormFields = new ArrayList();

CDatabaseField Db = new CDatabaseField();
Db.FieldName = FieldName; //FieldName is the input value fetched from the Windows Form
Db.PageNo = PageNo; //PageNo, Description, ButtonCommand are also fetched like FieldName
Db.Description = Description;
Db.ButtonCommand = ButtonCommand;
FormFields.Add(Db);
```

Now When I want to check only the `FieldName` of each object in the `ArrayList` (suppose there are many objects in the `ArrayList`). How can I do that??

I tried:

```
for(int i=0; i<FormFields.Count; i++) 
{
    FieldName = FormFields[i].FieldName;
}
```

But this is generating error (in the IDE). I am new to C# programming, so can someone help me with this??

> Error: Error 21 'object' does not contain a definition for 'FieldName'
>   and no extension method 'FieldName' accepting a first argument of type
>   'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Comment: can you use a list of `CDatabaseField` instead of array list?

Comment: `Recipe` the `OP's` best bet is to actually create a List of CDatabaseField  jsut as `Selman22` has pointed out..`List<CDatabaseField>`

Comment: Daniel, actually I am working on an old software and it implements arraylist named FormFields to store list of CDatabaseField, which is being used in thousand of places in the software. To change the arraylist to a list I need to change that in whole lot of places, which is right now not feasible.

Can you suggest me a way to get a particular fieldname from the object held in the arraylist??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured out the answer.
I tried to cast the objects for each object saved in the arraylist and finally could fetch the required field of each object:

```
for (int i = 0; i < FormFields.Count; i++)
{
     CDatabaseField Db = (CDatabaseField)FormFields[i];
     Label1.Text = Db.FieldName; //FieldName is the required property to fetch
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`ArrayList` holds objects. It's not generic and type safe.That's why you need to cast your object to access it's properties. Instead consider using generic collections like `List<T>`.

```
var FormFields = new List<CDatabaseField>();
CDatabaseField Db = new CDatabaseField();
...
FormFields.Add(Db);
```

Then you can see that all properties will be visible because now compiler knows the type of your elements and allows you to access members of your type in a type-safe manner.

Comment: I tried this method now but 'var' is generating an error in the visual basic : Error 1 The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Selman22, actually I am working on an old software and it implements arraylist named FormFields to store list of CDatabaseField, which is being used in thousand of places in the software. To change the arraylist to a list I need to change that in whole lot of places, which is right now not feasible. Can you suggest me a way to get a particular fieldname from the object held in the arraylist??

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed and based on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.item(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The Item returns an `Object`, so you may need to cast the returned value
>   to the original type in order to manipulate it. It is important to
>   note that `ArrayList` is not a strongly-typed collection. For a
>   strongly-typed alternative, see [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx).

However as an another option you can use the `foreach` loop instead of `for`. When `foreach` runs, it tries to `cast` element of `ArrayList` to `CDatabaseField` and if an element is not convertible to the `CDatabaseField` you will get an `InvalidCastException`:

```
foreach (CDatabaseField item in FormFields)
{
    FieldName = item.FieldName;
}
```

According to `foreach` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754(v=vs.71).aspx) and C#6 syntax the above code is equivalent to this:

```
var enumerator = FormFields.GetEnumerator();
try
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        CDatabaseField item = (CDatabaseField)enumerator.Current;
    }
}
finally
{
    var disposable = enumerator as IDisposable;
    disposable?.Dispose();
}
```